# Why is Hacker-Rank not Considering the proper Answer for the Regular Expression Question

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, testing

Here is the Question: You have a test string S.
Your task is to write a regular expression that matches only and exactly strings of form: abc.def.ghi.jkx , where each variable: a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,x  can be any single character except the newline.

Here is the Regular Expression I wrote:

```
/((\w+)?(\d+\d+)?)\.((\w+)?(\d+\d+)?)\.((\w+)?(\d+\d+)?)\.((\w+)?(\d+\d+)?)(\.\d+\d+)?(\.\d+\d+)?/g
```

I wrote this Regex as I discovered the different cases for the Hacker rank question. The interesting part is that I cases when tested using Regexer Website Tool, The cases are matching but they are not Matching on the Hacker rank website. Here is the Picture of both Working on Regexer and Not Working on Hacker rank:

[image: Image of The Working Regex on Regexr Website]

[image: Case 1 not working, even it was working with the same input in Regexr]

[image: Similar With Case 4]

[image: Case 6 Also]

I was trying to match the Regex Expression with the given Input. I wrote the Regex Expression for Every Case that was not working. Even If my all Regex is not Correct for all cases it should show for the ones that are Correct, but it is showing for some other common cases. I tested all using Regexr Tool for their given Input and its Matching there, but this Hacker rank is Not considering it.

Comment: The regex matches and it should not pass in these examples. As you wrote, it should only pass with this format: abc.def.ghi.jkx. These tests should not match.

Comment: Your regular expression makes no sense with regard to the challenge description; it only matches numeric digits.

Comment: @pointy You can see I have the Optional Parameter for the Characters too. Its not like I only matches the numeric only. I have used the "?" symbol to make choose any one type either numeric or characters if available. I think It makes clear sense

Comment: Well for "any single character" I would probably have gone with ".", as that's what "." means.

Comment: I know that '.' stands for any single character, but that is also not working. I have tried that in the very start. All cases are not matching

Comment: [A-Za-z]{0,3}\.[A-Za-z]{0,3}\.[A-Za-z]{0,3}\.[A-Za-z]{0,3}

Comment: Just try that, but I was trying to make you understand that the test cases were fine. Your regex match those cases and it is not what they ask for.

Comment: i tried your regex its not working for all cases

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the question. They were not asking you for an expression that matches all those strings you have tested against. They were asking for strings of this form to be matched abc.def.ghi.jkx Amongst other things you have ignored the requirement that any character except newline is OK and you have failed to start your search from the beginning of the string.

Comment: Try this ^[^\n]{3}.[^\n]{3}.[^\n]{3}.[^\n]{3}$ As @pointy has said you dont need to escape the . and to include all characters except newline you exclude newline.

Comment: All Cases got matched just leaving one, and the case is this: 123456789.2.2.2

Comment: @webdeveloper The intended solution seems to be `^.{3}(?:\.{3}){3}$`. `{3}`, `^` and `$` should be explained by the following challenges.

Comment: @InSync Its incorrect

Comment: @AHaworth your regex was almost right. 16 cases out of 17 got matched but the One case didn't matched. The case was 123456789.2.2.2 can you resolve it

Comment: @Pointy I take back my previous comment, you do need to escape the first dot at least, so to be safe I’d escape all of them. \.  I have no idea why this is needed and hope someone can tell us.

Comment: @AHaworth yea you need to escape a "." when you want it to match an actual ".", but not when you want it to match *anything*.

Comment: @AHaworth you both are right from your perspective but can anyone tell me the regex expression. I tried almost everything every time there are some cases which doesn't get matched.

Comment: Have you tried the regex I gave you but with the dots preceded by a backslash for me that works to give the right answer on all the strings you have shown so perhaps you could tell me what it isn’t working for? and also I’m not at all clear what ‘your perspective’ is in this case. Aren’t we trying to solve the same thing?